# There was an error reflecting type 'MAH.Tools.LicenseModel.CustomerLicense'

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

I have this methods in my License Class as shown below.

```
    public void CreateTestLincense(LicenseModel.CustomerLicense objData)
    {
        string data = CreateXML(objData);
        File.WriteAllText(licensePath, data);
    }
    private string CreateXML(Object YourClassObject)
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(YourClassObject.GetType());
        using (MemoryStream xmlStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlStream, YourClassObject);
            xmlStream.Position = 0;

            xmlDoc.Load(xmlStream);

            return xmlDoc.InnerXml;
        }
    }
```

But I'm trying to save the xml after passing its properties.

```
CustomerLicense custLic = new CustomerLicense();
custLic.CustomerId = 1;
custLic.Names = "David Okwudili";
custLic.Email = "michealdavid910@yahoo.com";
custLic.Phone = "09089786756";
custLic.ExpiringDate = DateTime.Now;
custLic.Serial = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
//Create XML Documant
MAH.Tools.Licensing.License lic = new MAH.Tools.Licensing.License(true);
lic.CreateTestLincense(custLic);
```

But it has been throwing an exception 'There was an error reflecting type' from `XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(YourClassObject.GetType());`.
Please i need help, Thanks.

Comment: XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(YourClassObject.GetType()); this is wrong

Comment: I have also tried `XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof( ));`

Comment: We need more information to help you.  1) What is the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the message, exception type, traceback **and inner exception**?  Usually the inner exception explains the problem.  2) Can you provide a [mcve] by sharing a simplified version of the type `LicenseModel.CustomerLicense`?  3) If not, try reading [Troubleshooting Common Problems with the XmlSerializer: Exceptions from the Constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302290.aspx#trblshtxsd_topic6).